# When is it okay to use primitive data types?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

It seems like Apple encourages the use of their classes, e.g. `NSNumber`, rather than the primitive C types like `int` and `float`, but sometimes it seems like overkill. When do you recommend using the latter over the former?

Comment: if primitive C types can suit your needs, why go for complex classes like `NSNumber` or `NSInteger` ? p.s. one advantage I can think of using complex classes is they are nullable

Comment: @ShivanRaptor `NSInteger` is a primitive type, not a class.

Comment: Oops. my bad. A nullable Objective-C primitive type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### When to use primitive

If you need to de work with your numbers (do math, modify the value...) then you should be using primitives, I prefer the Cocoa typedef's (`NSInteger`, `CGFloat`) but you might need to do specific things and have larger numbers with `long long` or something...

So it's up to your preferences and the use case.

### About NSNumber

`NSNumber` is a subclass of `NSValue`, this is useful when you need to work with objects like in APIs or even just working with containers like `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`.

Thus `NSNumber` is just a container for a primitive.

If you look at the [documentation for NSNumber](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you'll see a whole bunch of methods to create an object from each primitive type, and a bunch of methods to extract a primitive value from the object. There are a couple of compare methods and helpful methods to get string representations also. But what you'll notice is it's really only an object container for a primitive.

Comment: This is all good info but it doesn't answer the question. Why use primitive types versus `NSNumber`?

Comment: NSNumber is just a container for a primitive. If you need to work with it (do math, modify the value...) then you shouldn't be working with NSNumbers. Sorry if I missed the point. I'll edit my answer

Comment: @Daniel So what should you use it for?

Comment: @LionKing34: Putting numbers into Cocoa collections (set, array, dictionary) and easy serialization (NSKeyedArchiving) are two great uses for `NSNumber`

Comment: It really is about what your numbers are used for. If it's just numbers to represent options or static info, and you need to use them as objects in NSArray or something then NSNumber is up your street. But if you need to perform some calculations with your numbers then you would use primitives to do that, doesn't stop you creating NSNumbers after to send to some API if you need.

Answer (score 3):

Any answer to this question is going to be a mix of fact and opinion...

The question really should be the other way around - when should you use object wrappers instead of primitive values? Apple certainly does not encourage the use of `NSNumber` over primitive types unless there is a *need*.

Two reasons to use `NSNumber`:

1. You need an object, e.g. you need to store the primitive value (on its own, not as part of another object) in an object-based collection such as `NSArray`.
2. You need a "nullable" type, i.e. a type which is either represents a primitive value or the absence of such a value - often used in databases. Note that in this case defining and using your own value-based `struct` for your nullable primitive type might be a better option, or not, depending on the situation. (MS's .NET framework uses value-based nullable primitives while also having object-based primitive wrappers.)

Reasons you may want to avoid `NSNumber`:

1. It is more expensive - this isn't a case of *premature optimisation*, but of not using avoiding that as an excuse to write intentionally bad code!
2. It is immutable - if you're doing even a modest amount of math this will probably be a pain.

Remember types such as `NSInteger`, `CGFloat` etc. are not object types, just convenient `typedef`'s for language primitive types; and the framework APIs are full of uses of these types. Maybe unfortunately Apple never adopted a naming convention to distinguish between framework value types and object types.

HTH.

Answer (score 3):

[`NSNumber`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is a [toll-free bridged](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html) type to the underlying [CFNumber](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFNumberRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CFNumber). The documentation explicitly say that:

> CFNumber objects are *not intended as a replacement for C scalar values* and should not be used in APIs or implementations where scalar values are more appropriate and efficient.

So it is other way round. It is recommended NOT to use `NSNumber` except when needed. The documentation hints that it is primarily used for Cocoa property list and collection e.g. `NSArray`

Answer (score 1):

I generally go with objects when the value can be `nil`, otherwise I use primitive types (unless some API needs objects).